# What are the things that are allowed as keys in a python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose a = dict(),
a['key'] = value
what are the limitations of the  over here?? Can it be a list, tuple, string, another dictionary, integer??

Comment: Have a look at [the documentation for dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), this is clearly explained there.

Answer (score 1):

**A key must be immutable.**

That is the only limitations.
For example, 
You can use a tuple as the key if the items within tuple are immutable : `(1,2)`
But you can not do this `([1,2])`

Read up more about immutable and mutable types to get a clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

"The keys in dictionaries must be one of the immutable data types (numbers, strings, tuples)." - "Foundation of Python Programing" text book published by the Runstone Academy, Chapter 17.2. Nested Dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> A dictionary’s keys are *almost* arbitrary values. Values that are not [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys. Values that compare equal (such as `1`, `1.0`, and `True`) can be used interchangeably to index the same dictionary entry.

So immutable types like strings, numbers are ok. Mutable types like dictionaries and lists are not ok. Tuples are ok as long as they don't contain mutable elements. Dataclasses are ok if they have `frozen=True`.

If you need to enforce this at the type level, you can use `typing.Hashable`.